# MySQL Trigger serve password

Tags: mysql, encryption, view, triggers, passwords

is there a possibility to serve a password to a MySQL trigger?
I need that to encrypt my data in a BEFORE INSERT Trigger and to decrypt it in a view.
Maybe there is a way to store it in the current session?

Or is en- and decryption in the database layer a bad idea in general?

Thanks a lot =)

Comment: If the password is for login authentication iterated-salted-hasing is the currect method not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following trigger and event

**Schema:**

```
CREATE SCHEMA triggerTest;
USE triggerTest;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;
CREATE TABLE account 
(   id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    acct_num INT NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    insertDT DATETIME NOT NULL,
    updtBy VARCHAR(100) NULL -- user (or 'EVENTx' see below) that did the last insert
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Insert trigger:**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS acctBefInsTrig;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER acctBefInsTrig BEFORE INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.updtBy = @theVar;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Event:**

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `myEvt001`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT myEvt001
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
  BEGIN
    SET @theVar='myEvt001';
    INSERT account(acct_num,amount,insertDT) VALUES (102,2000,NOW());
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Test:**

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name='event_scheduler';
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

SET @theVar='Joe'; -- run this only once
SELECT @theVar; -- LINE A1
INSERT account(acct_num,amount,insertDT) VALUES (102,1000,NOW());

SELECT * FROM account; -- watch the Event put a new row in every minute

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = OFF;
SELECT * FROM account;
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+----------+
| id | acct_num | amount  | insertDT            | updtBy   |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 |      102 | 2000.00 | 2016-08-08 14:03:00 | myEvt001 |
|  2 |      102 | 1000.00 | 2016-08-08 14:03:17 | Joe      |
|  3 |      102 | 2000.00 | 2016-08-08 14:04:00 | myEvt001 |
|  4 |      102 | 1000.00 | 2016-08-08 14:04:27 | Joe      |
+----+----------+---------+---------------------+----------+
```

**Cleanup:**

```
DROP SCHEMA triggerTest;
```

Short narrative. If I in a user connection (MySQL Workbench, an app) create a User Variable (one with an @ sign), then the Insert Trigger will pick it up. Playing in concert with that is the shown Event which in running in a separate thread with its own connection and its own instance of its user variable `@theVar`. They do not interfere with each other or overwrite each other.

`LINE A1` above can be repeated run to show the Event does not write over our User Variable, as, well, it has its own.

The same holds true for Stored Procedures with User Variables as does with Triggers. If the User Variable `@theVar` has been set, it is available.